# JEST Verify the state from context api for a component under Higher Order Component HOC

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I am new to JEST & enzymes.
I've forked https://github.com/jscomplete/advanced-react/

I want to write unit test for Timestamp component at
https://github.com/jscomplete/advanced-react/blob/master/lib/components/Timestamp.js

so far without any luck

```
describe('Timestamp', () => {
    const timeToShow = new Date().toString();
    const testStore = {
        store : {
            data: {
                articles : { 
                    a : { id : 'a', title : 'sample a', body : 'life is mortal' },
                    b : { id : 'b', title : 'sample b', body : 'life after death is immortal' },
            },
            searchTerm : 'life',
            timestamp : timeToShow
        },
            getState: function(){
                return this.data;
            }   
        }       
    };
            
    it('TimeStamp render correctly', () => {
        const contextStore = testStore.store;
        const wrapper = mount(<TimeStamp />, testStore);
        
        console.log(wrapper.find('div').text());
    }); 
});
```

And getting this error

```
 FAIL  lib/components/__tests__/TimeStamp.js (5.184s)
   Timestamp › TimeStamp render correctly

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined

      at extraProps (lib/components/TimeStamp.js:33:51)
      at _class.usedState (lib/components/storeProvider.js:29:12)
      at new TimeStampContainer (lib/components/storeProvider.js:32:17)
      at node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:292:18
      at measureLifeCyclePerf (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:73:12)
      at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:291:16)
```

Comment: Enzyme shouldn't be expected to interpert testStore argument you're providing. Options argument has a specified interface. If the intention is to specify component `context`, try `mount(<TimeStamp />, { context: testStore })`. Shouldn't `getState` be a part of `store` object?

Comment: thanks @EstusFlask for your prompt response, now I'm seeing  other missing methods which would be resolved by Jest.fn. Please put your comments as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enzyme isn't expected to interpert `testStore` argument, [options argument](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html#mountnode-options--reactwrapper) has a specified interface.

If the intention is to specify `context` to class component, `context` option can be provided:

```
mount(<TimeStamp />, { context: testStore })
```

Since the component reads only from `store` property, `getState` likely should be a part of `store` object.